# Uncategorized Products Query

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I'm trying to get a list of uncategorized products in Magento. This is not necessarily a Magento question, but a general SQL question. I have a `product` table, and a `category` table, with a relation table called `category_product`. Every Product appears in two default categories (2 and 5). How would I construct a query (I can convert it into a Magento query) that returns all Products who don't have any categories other than 2 and 5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select p.product_id, p.name
from category_product cp
join product p on cp.product_id = p.product_id
group by cp.product_id
having sum(case when category_id in (2,5) then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: This will return products with categories 2, 5 and 7 for example as well though. `IN` is not exclusive.

Comment: Wow - thanks for the fast responses! Because of what I'm trying to do with the collection, the query needs to select from the Product table. How would you modify this to reflect that?

Comment: @MattFellows: No, it won't - where category is 7, the case statement will evaluate to 1 and the sum will therefore evaluate to greater than 1 - the having clause will therefore be false and the group will not be selected.

Comment: @Max: just join to the Product table - see the modified answer for an example. (In most other RDBMSs, the additional columns would need to be either used in an aggregate function or grouped, but this is not necessary in MySQL.)

Comment: I ended up doing it a bit differently because of how Magneto works, but thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in how to do this in Magento for an Adminhtml grid, here's the `_prepareCollection` function (tested in 1.6.1.0). The thing I wrote in the question about categories 2 and 5 ended up being a wild goose chase.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('status') /* so i can filter by enabled/disabled */
        ->joinField( 'category_product'
                   , 'catalog_category_product'
                   , 'category_id'
                   , 'product_id = entity_id'
                   , null
                   , 'left'
                   )
        ;

    /*ideally this should be an 'addFieldToFilter' but it doesn't work. Oh well.*/
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->where('at_category_product.category_id IS NULL')
        ;

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the most efficient, but it should work...

```
SELECT * from product p
INNER JOIN category_product cp on p.id = cp.product_id
WHERE cp.category_id IN (2, 5) AND cp.category_id NOT IN (SELECT category_id FROM category_product WHERE category_id NOT IN (2,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
select product.name
from product inner join category_product
on product.id = category_product.product
having count (*) < 2
```

I am assuming that the the only categories are indeed 2 and 5.